# NVidia's nView Desktop Manager keeps disabling itself

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop, nvidia-quadro

I'm running the latest version (149.77) of [nView Desktop Manager](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/nview/) on Windows 10 x64.  For reference I have NVidia Quadro P3000 notebook card.

I open the nView Desktop Mananger and `Enable`.  It runs fine for a while, then automatically disables.
This means I need to open the nView Desktop Manager again, then re`Enable`, for it to begin working again.

The time it runs before disabling varies.  I do not notice any trigger action either.

Fortunately, it remembers my settings.  But it partially defeats software's the purpose, if I have to keep telling it to start running again.

Does anybody have a workaround to have it re-start automatically?
Or any ideas how to keep it from disabling itself?
I can't imagine that this is the way it is supposed to "work".

I found this question on how to automatically start nView at Windows boot, but unfortunately, the answers there are not very helpful as  there is no `exe` file to start the manager, but it did get me to find the following information.

On my system, nView is started with:
`C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\nview\nvwdmcpl.dll", nViewMain`

I found this by:

1. finding nView Desktop Manager link in my start menu.
2. right-clicking -> Properties
3. copy the information from `Target`
4. I also notice that `Start in` has `"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\nview"`

I'm hoping that this information can be useful in:
1) somehow telling Windows to start this application when Windows starts
2) writing some ?script? that can keep the process running, or re-`Enable` it if it automatically `Disable`s.

Obviously, if someone knows why it's automatically disabling, and how to stop that, that would be even better.

---

*(I'm trying to get nView working, because Windows Virtual Desktop doesn't *yet* allow for Desktop renaming, and because the right-click menus, and the taskbar UI of nView, is so much better than the Windows implementation.)*